making otoscopic examination?
I came across a cause and effect sentence like this.

Some children have been reported to have narrow external ear canals, making otoscopic examination difficult and perhaps predisposing to stenosis.

Which expression better describes this sentence?

Some children have been reported to have narrow external ear canals and this makes otoscopic examination difficult and perhaps predisposes to stenosis.

Some children have been reported to have narrow external ear canals and this has made otoscopic examination difficult and perhaps has predisposed to stenosis.


Actually, the point that is stuck in my head is this: In cause and effect sentences, whatever the tense of the main clause is, should the tense of the participle clause be the same? In order not to break the sentence context.

There's no need in that sentence for "have been reported to have" and on one level it makes the sentence fodder for a joke: how does reporting that fact predispose to stenosis?

I got it as it is from the book

The tenses do not need to be the same.   Some children have narrow ear canals, making otoscopic examination difficult. But you could also say "... which makes otoscopic examination difficult".

Not blaming you for the sentence.

In your examples you're not using a participle clause but are coordinating two independent clauses with and.

yes I already converted an academic expression into a normal expression. but in such cause and effect sentences, I have seen that the tense of the cause sentence and the result sentence are the same. but if we think in the way you say, it seems more appropriate that the result of this sentence continues in the present tense. '' Some children have narrow ear canals, '' As you said, the sentence I wrote with this statement is the same. only '' have been reported '' confused me.

If you goal is to rewrite this sentence:

Some children have narrow external ear canals, making otoscopic examination difficult and perhaps predisposing them to stenosis.

as independent clauses coordinated with and, you could say:

Some children have narrow external ear canals and this makes otoscopic examination difficult and may also predispose (them) to stenosis.

The simple present is often used to state generalizations. If you were to say "may have predisposed them" you're mixing a generalization with a hypothesis.  There's no grammatical reason you can't do that, but in terms of presenting information clearly, it's better not to jumble observations and hypotheses together in that manner.  Also, the hypothesis isn't presented in general terms but in terms of these particular children. Better to focus on the feature and to generalize:

Some children have narrow external ear canals. Narrowness of the canal makes otoscopic examination difficult and may predispose such children to stenosis.

or

Some children have narrow external ear canals. Narrowness of the canal makes otoscopic examination difficult; it may  also predispose such children to stenosis.


In fact, to give an example: I wore tight denim trousers, making him uncomfortable. we could have written: I wore tight denim trousers and this made him uncomfortable.

Since the two events occurred  together in the past, two clauses each with their verb in the simple past would be grammatical, yes. But you could say "I had decided to wear tight jeans and that made him uncomforable".  One in the past perfect, the other in the past.

@emilywenly Also: present tense is always available for "general purposes" even if other parts of the sentence discuss other tenses. "In the past I've worn tight trousers and this makes him uncomfortable." "I'll avoid wearing tight trousers tomorrow as this makes him uncomfortable."

I think that option 1 has essentially the same meaning.
In 2 has made and has predisposed is the past tense and hence it is no longer the case, which is not what I would understand the original version to mean.
What was reported in the past continues to be a problem in the present.

As I mentioned above, shouldn't the tenses be the same?
